# Intel AppFramework $.mvc.route and transition

Tags: intel, appframework

I'm making an app using the Intel Appframework MVC but I can't find a way to use transition with $.mvc.route.

I tried to combine:

```
$.ui.loadContent("mydiv",false,false,"pop"); //from the documentation
```

with the mvc in this way:

```
$.ui.loadContent($.mvc.route("controller/action/"+var,false,false,"pop");
```

The result is that the controllor run and do his job, no transition showup and from console I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'indexOf'
```

Does anyone have suggestion? or can you advice me about a community somewhere for this framework?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from gitHub... Maybe usefull to somebody:

Call the route in this way:

```
$.mvc.route("controller/action/"+var+"/false/false/pop");
```

and then in the controller:

```
action:function(var1,var2,var3,var4){ $.ui.loadContent(var1,var2,var3,var4) }.
```

Hope could be usefull, it worked for me.